# Is $\text{Hom}(-,B)$ an exact functor?

Tags: category-theory

Is $\text{Hom}(-,B)$ an exact functor? In other words, if $$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$$ is an exact sequence, then is this mapped to an exact sequence by this functor?

I know that this is a contravariant functor, and that the image has an injective map. I'm not sure about the surjection though.

Comment: This is true iff $B$ is an injective object.

Comment: Try applying it to the sequence where $A=B=\Bbb Z$, with the map being multiplication by $n$, and $C=\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.